# Building a Repository Update method without attaching/detaching entities?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following update method, which seems to be working:

```
public Folder UpdateFolder(Folder folder)
        {
            Folder serverFolder = _db.Folders.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FolderId == folder.FolderId);
            if (serverFolder != null)
            {
                serverFolder.Title = folder.Title;
                serverFolder.Details = folder.Details;
            }
            SaveChanges();
            return serverFolder;
        }
```

I just noticed that most Update methods I've read about have calls to Entry.StateDetached and StateAttached - is what I've done above ok, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is okay.  `_db.Folders.FirstOrDefault` reads the `Folder` and it is attached to the context.

You would need to check if the entity was attached if you were simply passing in a `Folder` (without reading) and attempting to update it.

Basically, `Folder serverFolder = _db.Folders.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FolderId == folder.FolderId);` ensures that the Folder is attached so you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do `_db.SaveChanges();` instead of `SaveChanges();`